# Elements are added to a list twice

Tags: python

I was writing a program that generates a pack of cards, but for some reason that, at the moment, I can't see, the set of cards is added to the card_pack list twice. Can someone tell me why?

```
numbers = ("A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K")
symbols = ("clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades")
card_pack = []
cards = 0

while cards <= 52:
    for symbol in symbols:
        for number in numbers:
            card = number + " " + symbol
            card_pack.append(card)
            cards += 1
print("The pack has the following cards:")
for card in card_pack:
    print(card)
```

Comment: So, the outer while-loop is the problem. Note, the nested for-loops will *add exactly 52 items to your list*. Then, your while loops, since the condition `cards <= 52` will be true, will run the nested loops again, adding everything twice. Just remove the while-loop, it was never necessary.

Comment: no need for the while loop if you're creating every combination

Comment: while the while loop is indeed unnecessary, note that keeping it there will still work provided you check the correct inequality - which is `cards < 52`. You want to STOP when the value gets to exactly 52.

Comment: if the intention with your while loop is to handle an edge-case / prevent an error. It it typically better to just query your resulting list/tuple and throw an error message, then follow with normal operation afterward

Comment: Oooh yes you're totally right, while thinking about what the program would show in screen, I completely overlooked the implications of that = in <=. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @MariaG. yeah, but it is important to understand, that the while-loop is totally unnecessary. IN this case, the for-loops will deterministically add some exact number of items to the list, a nested loop gives you the *cartesian product* of the two lists, so for lists of size M and N, your resulting list (created by appending some item each iteration) will have size M*N

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
while cards <= 52:
```

When the two inner loops finish, `cards` will be equal to 52.  But your loop condition is *less than or equal* to 52, so the while loop executes again, and you get duplicates of each card.

You don't even need that outer while loop.  You have thirteen numbers and four suits, and the product of that is 52, so you *already know* that the innermost loop will execute 52 times.

Answer (score 0):

The logical error is explained above. If you are looking for a cleaner version of code. You can use

```
from itertools import product
[str(" ".join((i))) for i in (product(numbers, symbols))]
```

Comment: This code isn't clean, it has superfluous parentheses and calls to `str`, replacing the nice, descriptive names like `number` and `symbol` with `i` which tells us nothing.

Comment: IMO, clean would be something like `[f"{number} {symbol}" for symbol in symbols for number in numbers]`